# Entity Framework Mapping SQL Server tinyint to Int16

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, types

My Entity Data Model is giving me this error:

> Error 2019: Member Mapping specified
>   is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Int16[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]'
>   of ... is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.tinyint[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]'
>   of ...

I've tried deleting and recreating the property. I don't know what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A `tinyint` should get mapped to a .NET `byte`; `Int16` should be the corresponding type for a `smallint` in SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I was working with a tinyint but thinking of a smallint.

Comment: It also works with `byte` for `tinyint` and `short` for `smallint`.