# How to map tinyint to int?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have about a dozen fields marked as tinyint, which translates to a byte field. I'm finding that I'm having to do a lot of casting to int in my code to interact with integers.

Because of this, I'm thinking of changing the entity framework to read these as integers instead of bytes. Are there any implications of this, besides the chance that I may pass in an integer that is out of range of the tinyint? Am I just adding additional casts where I may not need them?

(I'm also thinking of just using integer instead in the database, because this isn't going to be a high usage DB.)

**Edit**

From Zach's comment below / [Entity Framework Mapping SQL Server tinyint to Int16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863162/entity-framework-mapping-sql-server-tinyint-to-int16) -- it looks like I can't just change the property from byte to int? The EF will throw an error? So, is there even a way to do what I'm thinking?

Comment: Have a glance at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863162/entity-framework-mapping-sql-server-tinyint-to-int16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't really be any issue using when you use Integers as the compiler actually optimizes the integers (I'm not mistaken.)

The best bet would be to change your database values from byte to Int. IMHO.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Sorry, what I think and write sometimes come out as two different things. I heard somewhere that I should rather use Int instead on short as Int get optimized. Is this correct?

Comment: it depends on the context. Arrays are different to variables, for example. Fields are tricky as padding comes into play. At the IL level, they are pretty much all identical once loaded onto the stack, but presumably `int` is easier to load as it doesn't need to be expanded. Unlikely to be a bottleneck, though. The bigger problem is the very-likely "unbox" - which is a kicker if the types don't match.

Comment: Thanks for the little lesson. Much appreciated.