# Specifing Column TypeName EntityFramework Core throws InvalidCastException

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity with an int property that I want to be stored as `tinyint` in Sql Server. I've successfully accomplished this with the fluent api.

However, when I query the database, i get `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

My (simplified) code:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .Property(m => m.Level)
            .HasColumnType("tinyint");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I change the `Level` property type to `byte`, I don't get the exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's because entity framework maps tinyint to a byte in dotnet. You must use byte.

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22714283/1932945

Comment: so then what is the purpose of `modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().Property(m => m.Level).HasColumnType("tinyint");`?

Comment: Sometimes a C# type could be one of multiple SQL types (e.g. string could by CHAR or VARCHAR or NVARCHAR) so it can be necessary to specify the SQL column type.