# EntityFrameworkCore - Map from MSSQL numeric to BigInteger

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, cryptocurrency

I have a MSSQL table where I have records which contains amount of cryptocurrencies in their smallest units (BTC-Satoshi, ETH-Wei...) This amounts can be pretty big (1 ETH is  1,000,000,000,000,000,000 Wei) so I wanted to store them in a NUMERIC(38,0) field type.

Then I have my client application where I am using Entity Framework Core (6), and in my entity class I have amount declared as a BigInteger. The problem is that I don't know how to do the mapping. I can use ValueConverter<BigInteger, decimal> but I (of course) get an error (overflow) when the number in the database is larger than the range of the Decimal type.

Are there any other options or what are the best practices? The other problem is that I would also  want to use aggregate functions (SUM) on this amounts, but I'm not sure if this is possible using   BigInteger and EF Core). I would also probably have problems with plain ADO and usage of SqlDataReader.GetDecimal (since I will get the same overflow error). Any advices?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what youre asking.  But see this answer for a "datatype in the database" and "data-type for c#" tension and workaround : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713949/how-do-i-map-a-c-sharp-int-to-a-sqlserver-tinyint-using-entity-framework-code-fi/22714283#22714283

Answer (score 0):

> I (of course) get an error (overflow) when the number in the database is larger than the range of the Decimal type.

If you need numbers larger than a .NET Decimal, you'll have to convert them to strings in SQL Server to read them on the client.

David

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, you probably mean that I still store the data in the numeric field on the SQL Server, and then cast it to string when querying the data? That means I would (in those cases) have to use FromSqlRaw functionality in EF Core - there is no mechanism that could cast (based on the model configuration) from numeric to string, and then convert it to BigInteger using ValueConverter or something similar?